# Audio Playback: Missing vowels

Tags: audio

I am new to audio processing, I have a dsPic33F and I wrote a simple audio playback (when you speak on the mic it is played immediately on the speaker). However some vowels don't produce any sound. The vowel "e" (like in engineering) is missing.

My question: Is this due to my sampling frequency, which is 8kHz?

Comment: Have you compared it to an audio recording on, say, a PC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"eh" produces a broad range of frequencies from below 100 Hz to over 7 kHz according to my Rode Microphone and spectrum analyser. That's little "k", big "H" and little "z" for kHz in case you didn't understand what I was suggesting!!

Why don't you use your PC to record your talking and analyse it in one of the freebie wav editors you can get to double check. You could also try outputting some pre-recorded speech as an audio input that your pic can try and reproduce to see if that helps.

Comment: I have used the audio editor [Goldwave](http://www.goldwave.com) to resample CD audio down to 8 kHz for playback out of a microcontroller using a 125 µs interrupt routine.

Comment: @tcrosley it looks nice dude - do you know if it does audio mastering effects such as multiband compression?

Comment: I don't think it has that feature, sorry.

Comment: 7KHz?...Are you sure?, in telephony a 8KHz sampling rate is used and it captures voiced speech well.

Comment: I'm absolutely sure, and it's a little k in kHz. I've got a recording studio and decent mics/equipment etc.. It even registered 200 Hz to over 5 kHz on my android phone's GE app. Just because telephony uses 8k sampling doesn't mean it makes an "eh" much less recognizable of course. Plenty of audible clues for the ear/brain to latch onto with very bandlimited audio.

Comment: Phone captures voice good enough for communication, but not particularly "well".  Well known shortcomings